# Error 1004 when setting HPageBreak location

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I moved a pagebreak in an Excel sheet by hand and recorded the following macro in the process because I want to automate it:

```
Sub RecordedMacro()
'
' RecordedMacro Macro
'
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A71")

End Sub
```

Running this recorded macro fails with an error 1004 ("application-defined or object-defined error"), even with an active sheet where I can do it manually without any problems.

I did some Internet searching and it appears that most people end up using HPageBreaks.Add instead of changing a pagebreak's location, but I'd like to know why this macro fails and if there is a way to make it work as I see no reason for throwing an error.

**EDIT:** The following line fails with an 1004, too:

```
Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location
```

Comment: Consider fixing your title, which says "Vpagebreak."

Comment: Now if I only had an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is slightly different than what you discovered, and doesn't require the `ResetAllPageBreaks`. In addition this one toggles `ScreenUpdating` to avoid the flicker of going back and forth:

```
Sub MoveThatHBreak()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A11")
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This is in Excel 2016. I stumbled on this answer because I could only record the move while in Page Break Preview, so figured maybe the same was true in VBA.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I tried to think what the difference between manually setting the pagebreak and setting it via VBA is in my case, and for reasons I do not fully understand I really have to switch the *view* first:

```
Sheets(sheetName).Activate
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
Sheets(sheetName).ResetAllPageBreaks
Set Sheets(sheetName).HPageBreaks(1).Location = ActiveSheet.Range("A71")
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

This makes not that much sense to me as all other operations on the HPageBreaks collection work without changing the view first, but if Excel requires it, I'll do it :).